# javascript - redirect if validation success, otherwise stay on the same page

Tags: javascript, validation

I have an HTML form and I'm using javascript to validate it. I want

- if the validation is successful -> auto redirect to another page.
- if the validation fails -> still stay on the form page (for user enter again).
  Just using javascript, how can I do it?

Here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function verifyNull() {
            if (!document.getElementById('username').value.trim().length) {
                alert('Please enter username');
            }
            else if (!document.getElementById('password').value.trim().length) {
                alert('Please enter password');
            }
        }
        function verifyEmail() {
            var x = document.getElementById('email').value;
            var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
                alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <title>Bài 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name = "myForm" method = "post" action = "registerd.html">
            Username <input type = "text" id = "username" name = "username"/><br />
            Password <input type = "password" id = "password" name = "password" /> <br />
            Email <input type = "text" id = "email" name = "email"/> 
            <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" onClick = "verifyNull();verifyEmail();"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if the validation is successful the validating function should return true, 
and if validations fails, return false.

```
function perform()
{
 if(isValid)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}
```

In your above code, the method verifyNull() and verifyEmail() should return true or false. Change the code as follows, and call the validate() method onsubmit of the form.

```
Remove the onclick event from the submit button and add an onsubmit event to the form.

<form name="myForm" action="registerd.html" onsubmit="return validate()">...</form>


function validate()
{
return (verifyNull() && verifyEmail());
}


function verifyNull(){
        var isValid = true;
        if(!document.getElementById('username').value.trim().length){
            isValid = false;
            alert('Please enter username');
        }
        else if(!document.getElementById('password').value.trim().length){
        isValid = false;
            alert('Please enter password');
        }
      return isValid;
    }
    function verifyEmail(){
        var x = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
        }
       return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `if else` statement. Assuming there's a variable to tell you whether validation passed, called `formValidation`:

`if(formValidation === true) {
        window.open("path/to/page.html", "_self");
    } else {
        // Do something else (the validation failed)
    }`

To give a more detailed answer (if you want one) then you need to provide more code.

Comment: Finally someone that shows me window.open! haha Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

HTML:-

```
<form  onsubmit="return validation()">
 .....
</form>
```

JavasScript:-

```
<script>
function validation() {
 var isValid = true;
 //perform your validation on form and update isValid variable accordingly.

 if(isValid) {
    window.location = ''; // your desired location
 }

 return false; // always return false to prevent form from submission.
}
</script>
```